# Trying to understand threading in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-c++

I am a C# programmer and i need to create a program in c++ now. What i'm trying to achieve is make an infinite thread and give it a sleep time.

In c# i could easily do this like

in main function

```
new Thread(taskfunction).Start();
```

and taskfunction

```
    private void taskfunction()
    {
    while(true){Thread.Sleep(2500); // do stuff}
    }
```

so this would work in the background as long as my program is on. I am trying to achieve the same thing in c++ like:

in main function

```
std::thread somethread(taskfunction);
somethread.join();
```

and taskfunction

```
void taskfunction()
{
while(true){this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2500));// Do Stuff}
}
```

So, while c# thread starts and moves on, c++ thread waits on `somethread.join();`. What is the difference and How can i achieve what i do in c# also in c++?

Thank you

Comment: Actually you have to join or detach your threads in C# and in C++

Comment: `join` means "wait until the thread is finished". That is not what you want. You can either `detach` which leaves the other thread alone or put the `std::thread`-object somewhere to `join` later. Just don't destroy the `std::thread`-object without `join`ing or `detach`ing first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[std::thread::join()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) block current thread of execution until thread, that you call it on, finishes it execution (returns from thread procedure).

This is useful, if (for example) you want to create temporary threads, that should perform some computations and generate results, that you wait on and use immediately.

In your case, you should not use this method - at least not immediately after thread's creation. Note, however, that `std::thread` **must** be either joined or detached:

> `std::thread::~thread()`
>
> Destroys the thread object.
>
> If `*this` has an associated thread (`joinable() == true`), `std::terminate()` is called.

So you need to either:

- [detach()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) thread if it should be executed independently from main thread (resources allocated by thread will be automatically released when thread finishes its execution)
- proceed in `main()` and when you reach end of your program, signal thread, that it should end and then `join()` it.

Comment: detach is dangerous. You need to set something up to wait for the thread's completion to be safe, in which case you're far better off always using join.

Comment: Join is dangerous.  Waiing for thread completion can easily result in processes that wil not shut down.  You are far better off never using join(), using app-lifetime threads/threadpools and never explictly terminating threads.   The OS is much better at terminating threads than any user code and, if possible, should be allowed to do it at process termination.

Comment: @MartinJames `join` can only do that if you write a thread func that never ends. You should not write a thread func which never ends. `join` encourages writing good code, thread funcs that end safely (usually signaled by another thread). `detach` encourages writing unsafe code. It's not about when a thread is terminated at the os level, as that performance concern is a non-issue in 99% of situations, it's about well defined code scope.

Comment: ?? I've been writig app-lifetime threads for decades, no problem.  More problems arise when devs. try to terminate threads before process end than when they do not. For just one instance, GUI frameworks cannot wait in even-handlers for anything, including calling join() on threads that may, or may not, terminate anytime soon or, worse, are themselves waiting on some action queued to the GUI framework, (deadlock).

Comment: @MartinJames I cannot see usage of thread, that is started **after** `main()` starts and ends **after** `main()` finishes. For me, that's obviously a defect in threads hierarchy. I always forced threads to sync with (join) their child threads, which ensures proper execution flow and helps with resource management (you have well defined lifetime for every single object). `join()` really helps achieve this aspects. Since it blocks, it's dangerous - but properly used can be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`detach()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/detach/) the thread to make it independent.

Answer (score 0):

use std::tread::detach(). this function separates the thread of execution from the thread object, allowing execution to continue independently. Any allocated resources will be freed once the thread exits.